# Swap a draw with an image in Google Doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have various Word documents (.docx) saved in Google Drive, everyone has inside a draw composed of text, borders, and a pen-draw, grouped together.

When opened in Google Doc the .docx files to edit, the group appear as a draw composed of the same elements except the pen-draw that is missing.

So I need to solve this, 2 options:

1. Replace the draw with a saved image
2. Edit the draw and put inside an image, save&close the draw

Since it is an operation repeated ten times every day I want to find a way to automate this with google appscripts

Any suggestion ?

Comment: I don't think what you're asking is possible with Google App Scripts unless you convert your files from `docx`. Is that an option? You can always convert it back to `docx`.

Comment: What is a "draw"?

Comment: Can you provide a sanitized copy of the doc that you want to copy?

Comment: @Emel: see it here [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-V83oQypkjUurJ4onmvcUANdGvt3in61/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=103428272074687378874&rtpof=true&sd=true)